# FOR LOOP with WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

This question has been posed before but not specifically for Oracle database.

Can a FOR LOOP be filtered with WHERE clause?  For example I would like to do something like:

```
--LOG ERRORS
FOR err in c_errors WHERE trx_type='CYCLE_COUNT'
LOOP

    ...do some stuff

END LOOP;
```

This code gives error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHERE" when expecting one of the following ...
```

Is there proper syntax for this?

Here is the cursor definition.  It grabs cycle count and adjustment transaction types.  But in the log errors section mentioned above, I only want to report on cycle count errors.  Sure I could use separate cursors, but was trying to accomplish using one.

```
    CURSOR c_errors IS
        SELECT DISTINCT CC_ENTRY_INTERFACE_ID INTERFACE_ID
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE
            ,creation_date
            ,LAST_UPDATE_DATE
            ,'CYCLE_COUNT' TRX_TYPE
        FROM mtl_cc_interface_errors
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT TRANSACTION_INTERFACE_ID
            ,ERROR_EXPLANATION
            ,CREATION_DATE
            ,LAST_UPDATE_DATE
            ,'ADJUSTMENT'
        FROM mtl_transactions_interface 
        WHERE process_flag=3 
            AND error_code IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY last_update_date DESC;
```

Comment: For what?  Please describe what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: I guess I can just use IF after entering the loop, but it doesn't really achieve the desired result since it will still be looping through all the records selected by cursor.  Maybe a separate cursor is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FOR err in c_errors WHERE trx_type='CYCLE_COUNT'

This is semantically incorrect.

What you can do, as one of the options, is to create a parameterized cursor. 
Here is [an example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e6660c47cb3878ebc76fbf64efa7c767):

Case #1: Parameter is null. All rows returned

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  cursor l_cursor ( param1 varchar2) is
    select *
      from (
            select level  as c1
                 , 'cycle_count' as trx_type
              from dual
            connect by level < 3
            union all
            select level  as c1
                 , 'adjustemnt' as trc_type
              from dual
            connect by level < 3
           ) q
    where param1 is null
       or trx_type = param1;
begin
  -- param1 = null. No filter applied
  for r in l_cursor(null) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('C1: ' || to_char(r.c1) || '; ' ||
                         'TRX_TYPE: ' || r.trx_type);
  end loop;
end;
```

Result:

```
CNT: 1; TRX_TYPE: cycle_count
CNT: 2; TRX_TYPE: cycle_count
CNT: 1; TRX_TYPE: adjustemnt
CNT: 2; TRX_TYPE: adjustemnt
```

Case #1: Filtering by `TRX_TYPE`

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  cursor l_cursor ( param1 varchar2) is
    select *
      from (
            select level  as c1
                 , 'cycle_count' as trx_type
              from dual
            connect by level < 3
            union all
            select level  as c1
                 , 'adjustemnt' as trc_type
              from dual
            connect by level < 3
           ) q
    where param1 is null
       or trx_type = param1;
begin
  -- param1 = 'cycle_count'
  for r in l_cursor('cycle_count') loop
    dbms_output.put_line('C1: ' || to_char(r.c1) || '; ' ||
                         'TRX_TYPE: ' || r.trx_type);
  end loop;
end;
```

Result:

```
C1: 1; TRX_TYPE: cycle_count
C1: 2; TRX_TYPE: cycle_count
```

Comment: Dig it.  I  will give this a try.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeap, looks like this is going to work for me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Nick's answer it's a nice explanation.

Here is another example of how to use it, by declaring the cursor inline with the **FOR** syntax:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r_product IN (
        SELECT 
            product_name, list_price 
        FROM 
            products
        WHERE list_price > 120
        ORDER BY list_price DESC
    )
  LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line( r_product.product_name ||
        ': $' || 
        r_product.list_price );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Source:
https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-cursor-for-loop/

Comment: But there is nothing there that is filtering the cursor selection.  Its looping through the entire select list, which is what I did not want to do.

Comment: You can treat the cursor as any normal select statement.